# Visual Studio Code shows no INTERNET connection

Tags: wifi, visual-studio-code

At first Vscode was running perfectly.
But suddenly after some days VScode is not working.
I am connected to my wifi but VScode shows

[image]

I have uninstalled Vscode and all the related directories but it was helpless.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is complaining that it can't connect to the "Extensions Marketplace", ie to a specific server/system that is running on the Internet. That is not the same as being unable to connect to the Internet itself. Maybe the Market is simply offline at the time of the error? Maybe there is a DNS issue with the Internet, or even your WiFi router, being unable to resolve the Market's hostname to an IP address? Who knows. There are tons of reasons why a connection to a specific server could not be established.

Comment: At right bottom screen it says "XHR failed".

Comment: and also "net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED"

Comment: Sounds like your machine's proxy settings are not configured properly, or your WiFi network is not providing the correct proxy details.

Comment: wifi is working fine on all other platforms..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with me for some time.It was a issue with the proxy i used before.

Solution:
Goto Environment Variables Settings in windows and remove the variable with the proxy address.

good luck!
[image]